# Sorting 2-D char array alphabetically in RAD Studio XE3

Tags: c, c++builder

I'll try to clarify things as clear as possible before I even try to ask for anything.
So I'm currently studying at high school as a programmer. Recently my teacher asked of me to create a VCL forms application in RAD Studio XE3, kinda like C program, but only with forms and stuff.

I had to create matrix N*M (eventually 2-D char array) with Latin chars stored into it. Then I had to sort it with insertion sort method. So what have I done so far is, I defined the array, I created a StringGrid1 from which those chars are read. I stored them into 2-D char array, but the hardest thing for me is to make it sort those chars in **alphabetical** order, but I don't have to sort everything together, only each row individually, and then make the final changes appear back onto StringGrid1 (that's not the problem).

As I said before, I'm having some major difficulty making that sort thing work. I've gone through a billion examples, searched Google for like solid AGE. It would've been nothing if those were integer values, but I hardly can even bear the thing that C hates String values.

My program:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brx9X.jpg

This is how I managed to read from StringGrid1 chars and store them into array[i][j].
mmax and nmax is used for telling how far to read, as user can chose the row and col count himself.

```
    for(int i=0; i < mmax; i++)    //Rindas (kolonnas)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < nmax; j++) //Kolonnas (rindas)
            {
                char * temp = (char*)(StringGrid1->Cells[i][j]).c_str();    //Nolasam no Edit lauka char elementu
                array[i][j] = temp[0];       //Piešķiram masīvam šo elementu
                ListBox1->Items->Add(array[i][j]);    //Ierakstam ListBox1 masīva elementu
                Button3->Enabled = False;
                Button6->Enabled = True;

            }
    }
StringGrid1->Options = StringGrid1->Options >> goEditing;  //Neatļauj lietotājam rediģēt StringGrid1 laukus
```

So, now for the sort thing... How do I do that? I'm out of clues. How does one sort chars from 2-D, sot that each row should be sorted individually, for example, there are 5 rows, and each row is being sorted one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you are not filling your array correctly.  This line:

```
char * temp = (char*)(StringGrid1->Cells[i][j]).c_str();
```

Obtains a **temporary** `String` instance from the `Cells` property, grabs a pointer to its internal data via its `c_str()` method, and then **frees the `String`** when it goes out of scope, leaving the pointer dangling so that it is not valid on this line:

```
array[i][j] = temp[0];
```

Your array *happens* to end up with the right character values, but only because a `String`'s internal data is reference counted, and the `TStringGrid` still has active references to the original `String` values, so the `String` data does not get physically freed from memory yet, so your `temp` pointer is still pointing at the original memory that is still alive, but that is an implementation detail that you should not rely on.

Use this instead:

```
String temp = StringGrid1->Cells[i][j];
array[i][j] = temp[1]; // or temp.c_str()[0]
```

Or this:

```
array[i][j] = StringGrid1->Cells[i][j][1]; // or StringGrid1->Cells[i][j].c_str()[0]
```

Now, with that said, the actual sorting logic is fairly easy, especially if you use the STL to do the actual sorting for you, eg:

```
#include <algorithm>

for(int i=0; i < mmax; i++)
{
    std::sort(&(array[i][0]), &(array[i][nmax]));
}
```

If you need more control over the sorting, you can use a custom comparison function:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool my_compare(char a, char b)
{
    // return true if the first argument is less than the second, otherwise return false.
}

for(int i=0; i < mmax; i++)
{
    std::sort(&(array[i][0]), &(array[i][nmax]), my_compare);
}
```